# How to compare to net.sf.json.JSONObject.NULL constant in EL expression

Tags: json, jsp, jstl, el

I'm using `net.sf.json.JSONObject`. A `null` value in the JSON object is not equivalent to Java `null`. The statement, `<c:if test='${not empty obj.value}'>` is not working. Is there any way to compare JSON `null` in the JSTL tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already on EL 3.0+, then you can do it as follows:

```
<%@ page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject" %>
...
<c:if test="${JSONObject.NULL eq obj.value}">
```

If you're not on EL 3.0 yet and thus cannot import constants into EL scope as given above, then use the work around given below which basically checks the `Class#getSimpleName()`:

```
<c:if test="${obj.value['class'].simpleName eq 'JSONNull'}">
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. But when I print the instance using obj.value.class.simpleName it is printed as JSONNull

Comment: @Manojkumar - I've posted an update. I hope it works for you.

Comment: instanceof threw an error 'invalid expression'. I tried with `<c:if test='${obj.value .class.simpleName eq "JSONNull"}'>` it worked. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Great! I've incorporated the same into my answer so that it can be useful for someone in the future. Wish you success!